# angular and binding to a key

Tags: angularjs, binding

My data looks something like this:

```
$scope.Statuses = [
 {"status_id":1, "status":"A"},
 {"status_id":2, "status":"B"},
 {"status_id":3, "status":"C"},
];

$scope.Items= [
 {"item_id":1, "item":"X", "status_id":3},
 {"item_id":2, "item":"Y", "status_id":2},
 {"item_id":3, "item":"Z", "status_id":1},
];
```

In my HTML, I am looping through the Items and displaying them in a grid.  So at one point I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```
<div>{{Statuses[Item.status_id]}}</div>
```

For Item "X" I'd expect to see a status of "C", etc.  It seems like it should be more like, "Statuses[status_id = Item.status_id]}}", but for the life of me I can't find anything like this.  Is this even possible?  I can return the "status" with the Item if I have too, but that seems to defeat the purpose in this case, plus it potentially messes up other things later on.

In fact, as I write this I can already see that even if I get the key matching (status_id = Item.status_id), I'm not telling it which field it would need to display to get the correct results.

Comment: You have an array of objects, but you are trying to take an element of the array (which is an object) by an index, that's wrong. What do you actually want to see in the div?

Comment: Yeah, I get that (which is why I said I know it needs to be something like status_id = Item.status_id), but is what I want to do possible?  Is there some way to bind like that?

Comment: You need to create a method in your controller, pass status_id into it, then in the method find the status from first array and return what you need. Need an example or is it already clear?

Comment: So it would be something like: "<div>{{ShowStatus(Item.status_id)}}</div>", and then use the function to select the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.Statuses = [
      {"status_id":1, "status":"A"},
      {"status_id":2, "status":"B"},
      {"status_id":3, "status":"C"},
    ];

    $scope.Items = [
       {"item_id":1, "item":"X", "status_id":3},
       {"item_id":2, "item":"Y", "status_id":2},
       {"item_id":3, "item":"Z", "status_id":1},
    ];

    $scope.getStatus = function (val) {
        var foundStatus = $scope.Statuses.filter(x => x.status_id === val)[0];
        return foundStatus.status;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-repeat="item in Items">
        <div ng-bind="item.status_id"></div>
        <div ng-bind="getStatus(item.status_id)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: you can of course use {{getStatus(item.status_id)}}, but I do not like such approach, because in this case your end-user might see {{}} if you client scripts takes some time to perform some actions, like AJAX calls, for instance. Yes, there is ng-cloak directive which assists to solve the issue, but I personally do not like it and it is off-topic in this question.

Comment: Ok, I totally get what you are doing here now, so thanks.  Unfortunately the original programmer is using some "adaptive-grid" directive to build and display the grid, and it isn't giving me access back to the original $scope for some reason.  Still, I see what I need to do, and now it is just a matter of getting it to work in my scenario.  Thanks so much!!